# Get timestamp and member's email of Mailchimp campaign clicks

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0, mailchimp-api-v3

According to Mailchimp documentation, it is possible to get the **timestamp plus the email address** of members who **opened** a campaign email.

https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/api/open-reports/list-campaign-open-details/

> members: An array of objects, each representing a list member who opened a campaign email. Each members object will contain information about the number of total opens by a single member, as well as timestamps for each open event.

```
{
  "campaign_id": "string",
  "list_id": "string",
  "list_is_active": true,
  "contact_status": "string",
  "email_id": "string",
  "email_address": "string",
  "merge_fields": {
    "property1": null,
    "property2": null
  },
  "vip": true,
  "opens_count": 0,
  "opens": [
    {
      "timestamp": "2019-08-24T14:15:22Z"
    }
  ],
  "_links": [
    {
      "rel": "string",
      "href": "string",
      "method": "GET",
      "targetSchema": "string",
      "schema": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

However, it doesn't seem that the equivalent call **clicks** exists. The API endpoint that retrieves click information is inconsistent and **doesn't have this information**. (See below).

And so... How can I get **timestamp plus the email address** of members who **clicked**?

https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/api/link-clickers/list-clicked-link-subscribers/

> members:
> An array of objects, each representing a member who clicked a specific link within a campaign.

```
{
  "email_id": "string",
  "email_address": "string",
  "merge_fields": {
    "property1": null,
    "property2": null
  },
  "vip": true,
  "clicks": 0,
  "campaign_id": "string",
  "url_id": "string",
  "list_id": "string",
  "list_is_active": true,
  "contact_status": "string",
  "_links": [
    {
      "rel": "string",
      "href": "string",
      "method": "GET",
      "targetSchema": "string",
      "schema": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The second API call doesnt have a timestamp field so you will not be able to get that data

```
{
  "members": [
    {
      "email_id": "string",
      "email_address": "string",
      "merge_fields": {
        "property1": null,
        "property2": null
      },
      "vip": true,
      "clicks": 0,
      "campaign_id": "string",
      "url_id": "string",
      "list_id": "string",
      "list_is_active": true,
      "contact_status": "string",
      "_links": [
        {
          "rel": "string",
          "href": "string",
          "method": "GET",
          "targetSchema": "string",
          "schema": "string"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "campaign_id": "string",
  "total_items": 0,
  "_links": [
    {
      "rel": "string",
      "href": "string",
      "method": "GET",
      "targetSchema": "string",
      "schema": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

So unfortunately you are only able to get the timestamp of when someone opens the email, but not the timestamp of when the link in the email is clicked